# Does washing rice in a non-stick pot erode the non-stick coating over time?

Tags: rice, non-stick

I usually wash my rice in the pot that comes with my rice cooker (Tiger JBV-10CU) which is non-stick. I've heard that rice can be abrasive to the non-stick coating if you move it around in the pot as your washing it. Is there any evidence that supports this claim?

Comment: I [tried](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767881/can-the-scratch-susceptibility-of-a-given-material-be-determined-given-the-brea/767893#767893)

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not.

Nonstick coatings, while softer than steel, are considerably harder than rice grains.

Comment: Rice can have harder minerals and dirt/sand that can scratch, best to rinse it first...

Comment: Sure, if your rice had a bunch of sand/rocks in it, then that would scratch the pot.  But, if your rice has rocks and sand, then rinsing it in a pot isn't adequate, and you'd know that pretty quick if you tried to eat it.

Answer (score 1):

here is evidence. someone posted on blog. korean probably using rice cooker every day(almost used 4year) and washed rice inside the pot and coating has peeled off.

once it started peel off. it will be peeled faster and faster. best is using stainless bowl. or just washing rice with water.(dont massage ur rice with hands)

[image: https://mblogthumb-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAyMjEwMDFfODAg/MDAxNjY0NTUxMzQwMjA2.LThn79oYlytFBOuSX0puJoxGPDfeqFaEqMAEdL44kVog.TTFz-_bCfy15G-QUEXCDnpG8TlCNqm_nsn5sCJCF2LEg.JPEG.happyandante/IMG_1777.JPG?type=w800]